# Calculating non-decimal digit sequences with sympy

Tags: sympy, number-formatting

Is there a direct way to generate the sequence of digits in an arbitrary non-decimal base for irrational numeric values directly in sympy?

What I need is to e.g. obtain the the first 1024 binary digits of pi in an array-like data structure; but couldn't find such a function despite intensive search.
For those who care: the intended use is for generating test-instances for combinatorial optimization whose generation can easily be communicated.

I know how to do it algorithmically, but would prefer to use a builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
In [6]: from sympy import pi

In [7]: bin(pi.evalf(1000)._mpf_[1])[2:1024+2]
Out[7]: '1100100100001111110110101010001000100001011010001100001000110100110001001100011001100010100010111000000011011100000111001101000100101001000000100100111000001000100010100110011111001100011101000000001000001011101111101010011000111011000100111001101100100010010100010100101000001000011110011000111000110100000001001101110111101111100101010001100110110011110011010011101001000011000110110011000000101011000010100110110111110010010111110001010000110111010011111110000100110101011011010110110101010001110000100100010111100100100001011011010101110110011000100101111001111110110001101111010001001100010000101110100110100110001101111110110101101011000010111111111101011100101101101111010000000110101101111110110111101110001110000110101111111011010110101000100110011111101001011010111010011111001001000001000101111100010010110001111111100110010010010010100001100110010100011110110011100100010110110011110111000010000000000111110010111000101000010110001110111111000001011001100011011010010010000011011000011100010101011101001110011010'
```